How do I remove the knobs from my door latch?
The bolt on an egg-shaped exterior door knob fell out.


With the knob still attached, I tried to thread the bolt back onto the screw in the inside, which you can see a little better here:

But this didn't work. I don't know if that's because that screw on the inside has too much play in it or if something is wrong with the threading (pushing against the screw pushes it into the door frame). I've replaced a number of door knobs and deadbolts but never saw internals of a door like this. Does this look like a normal egg shaped knob I might buy today, or is there something different about this one (it's probably 30 years old)?
Before attempting replacing, I was going to take it apart to see if I could thread the bolt onto the screw while out of the door, though honestly not sure if that'll be any easier because the screw will still be recessed into that black frame structure presumably even if I get it out of the door. Regardless, to do this or to replace, I need to remove this from the door anyway. Is the correct way to do this to unscrew these little screws under the handle?


what is preventing you from removing the screws in the handle?

This is an exterior door and it's cold outside. I don't have a spare handle like this to replace it with. The reason I asked first is that it looked odd to me. For example, that black casing I hadn't seen before (or at least the internals of it). I just didn't want to start taking things apart, or try to force removal and break something if I didn't understand how it should be removed. Like removing that screw presumably released the handle, but then do I pull the plate off with force? It's probably been painted over so it could be harder to remove than it should be.

Thanks. I'll give it a try.

Yeah, those set screws should allow the knobs to come off, and then you can pull the escutcheon plates. The escutcheon either just pulls off or threads off of a central stud or sleeve.
There were a variety of designs back then (probably more like 50 years ago--this doesn't look like 90s hardware). You won't break anything if you don't get gorilla with it. Since your latch is already defunct you have nothing to lose.

That looks like it may be of a vintage where the set screws on the knob needs to be loosened, and then the knob needs to be unscrewed from its shaft by rotating it counterclockwise.
